# An infinite subset of a closed finite interval?

Tags: real-analysis

The question is as follows:

> Let $I=\left [ a,b \right ]$ be an interval in $\mathbb{R}$ and let $S\subset I$ be an infinite subset.  Prove that there exists a nested sequence of intervals $\left \{ I_{n} \right \}=\left \{ \left [ a_{n}, b_{n}\right ] \right \}$ contained in $I$ such that $S \cap I_{n}$ is infinite $\forall \  n.$

This question has me very confused.  How can we have an infinite subset of a closed finite interval?

As much as I love to share my own ideas and work with you guys, I think I am at a loss here.

Can anyone provide an explanation?

Comment: Infinite in the sense that there are an infinite number of points, not in the sense that its spatial extent is infinite. For instance, any closed interval $[a,b]$ with $a<b$ is infinite since there are an infinite number of real numbers in there.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen There is a term in the book I'm reading (Calculus by Adams) which confuses me: "Continuous functions on closed, finite intervals". Isn't a closed interval necessarily a finite interval? Why do we need here the term "finite", too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Bolzano Weierstrass theorem. The set $S$ has an accumulation point $c\in I$ and let $I_n=[c-1/n,c+1/n]\cap I$. Show that this sequence of intervals works as desired.

---

On second reading the problem appears trivial as we can choose each $I_n$ as $I$ itself. Perhaps there is some extra hypotheses on the intervals $I_n$.

Comment: Well, it makes sense to impose the condition that the lengths of the intervals tend to $0$ and you have already answered the question with this added condition.